# Spark LightGBM Predict dataframe datatype different from printSchema of output datatype

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-mllib, lightgbm

I want to transform one of the column data type in my dataframe to string using a UDF.

When I `printSchema` of my dataframe, that column indeed shows `vector` datatype, However when i use my UDF to transform the vector to string, I get error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(probability)' 

due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, '`probability`' is of 

struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> type.;;
```

**imports**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import com.microsoft.ml.spark.{LightGBMClassifier,LightGBMClassificationModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel, PipelineStage}
```

**UDF**

```scala
val vecToString = udf( (xs: Vector) => xs.toArray.mkString(";"))
```

**DataFrame (printSchema)**

```scala
val inputData = spark.read.parquet(inputDataPath)
val pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load(modelPath)
val predictions = pipelineModel.transform(inputData)

 # Selecting only 2 columns from predictions DF:

 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = false)

+-----------------------------------------+----------+
|probability                              |prediction|
+-----------------------------------------+----------+
|[0.2554504562575961,0.7445495437424039]  |1.0       |
|[0.7763149003135102,0.22368509968648975] |0.0       |
```

**Convert probability column to string using my UDF**

```scala
val tmp = predictions
                  .withColumn("probabilityStr" , vecToString($"probability"))
```

And this is where the above error occurs.

Also tried:

```scala
val vecToString = udf( (xs: Array[Double]) => xs.mkString(";"))

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(probability)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<double> type, however, '`probability`' is of struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> type.;;
```

When I used a different model (not Light GBM, this works fine. Could it be due to type of model used?)

Comment: Are you sure the vector type is correct? Try using the `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` variant.

Comment: yes tried that too

Comment: I see, I just noticed that you used `vecToString($"probability.values"))` when calling the udf. Did you try `vecToString($"probability"))` (when the udf accepts a Vector of `ml` type)?

Comment: oh, actually i used `vecToString($"probability"))` first then tried `vecToString($"probability.values"))` and both didnt work